# Configurar dos Endpoint en SOAP webservice con SpringBooot

Tags: webservice, soap, spring-boot, wsdl

espero se encuentren bien y me puedan ayudar con el siguiente problema.

Quiero configurar un webservice SOAP el cual brinde varios servicios, basado en un ejemplo donde creo el siguiente archivo usuarios.xsd...

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://www.servicio.com/usuarios-ws"
           targetNamespace="http://www.servicio.com/usuarios-ws" elementFormDefault="qualified"> 
        //Defino la estructura de mi xsd
</xs:schema>
```

La clase que corresponde al Endpoint para mi servicio esta de la siguiente forma.

```
@Endpoint
public class UsuariosEndpoint {
    private static final String NAMESPACE_URI = "http://www.servicio.com/usuarios-ws";
    @Autowired
    private UsuarioService usuarioService;

    @PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "getUsuarioByIdRequest")
    @ResponsePayload
    public GetUsuarioByIdResponse getUsuario(@RequestPayload GetUsuarioByIdRequest request) {
        GetUsuarioByIdResponse response = new GetUsuarioByIdResponse();
        UsuarioInfo usuarioInfo = new UsuarioInfo();
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(usuarioService.getUsuarioById(request.getIdUsuario()), UsuarioInfo);
        response.setUsuarioInfo(usuarioInfo);
        return response;
    }

}
```

Por ultimo la clase de configuración.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWs
public class WSConfig extends WsConfigurerAdapter {

                @Bean
                public ServletRegistrationBean messageDispatcherServlet(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
                                MessageDispatcherServlet servlet = new MessageDispatcherServlet();
                                servlet.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
                                servlet.setTransformWsdlLocations(true);
                                return new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, "/soapws/*");
                }

                @Bean(name = "usuarios")
                public DefaultWsdl11Definition defaultWsdl11Definition(XsdSchema studentsSchema) {
                                DefaultWsdl11Definition wsdl11Definition = new DefaultWsdl11Definition();
                                wsdl11Definition.setPortTypeName("UsuariosPort");
                                wsdl11Definition.setLocationUri("/soapws");
                                wsdl11Definition.setTargetNamespace("http://www.servicio.com/usuarios-ws");
                                wsdl11Definition.setSchema(usuariosSchema);
                                return wsdl11Definition;
                }

                @Bean
                public XsdSchema usuariosSchema() {
                                return new SimpleXsdSchema(new ClassPathResource("xsds/usuarios.xsd"));
                }
}
```

Hasta aquí todo bien, puedo obtener información que proporciona este servicio.Lo que quiero es utilizar un segundo xsd, con su respectivo Endpoint, que seria el siguiente.

El segundo xsd compras.xsd...

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://www.servicio.com/compras-ws"
           targetNamespace="http://www.servicio.com/compras-ws" elementFormDefault="qualified"> 
        //Defino la estructura de mi xsd
</xs:schema>
```

La clase que corresponde al Endpoint para mi servicio esta de la siguiente forma.

```
@Endpoint
public class ComprasEndpoint {
    private static final String NAMESPACE_URI = "http://www.servicio.com/compras-ws";
    @Autowired
    private ComprasService comprasService;

    @PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "getCompraByIdRequest")
    @ResponsePayload
    public GetCompraByIdResponse getCompra(@RequestPayload GetCompraByIdRequest request) {
        GetCompraByIdResponse response = new GetCompraByIdResponse();
        CompraInfo compraInfo = new CompraInfo();
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(compraService.getCompraById(request.getIdCompra()), CompraInfo);
        response.setCompraInfo(compraInfo);
        return response;
    }

}
```

No se como configurar los dos servicios en el mismo proyecto ya que DefaultWsdl11Definition que por lo que entiendo me genera el WSDL solo genera uno, si me pudieran ayudar por favor. Muchas gracias de antemano.